# Anyone Recognizes this Limit? About Inverse Laplace Transform

Tags: limits, probability-theory, laplace-transform

[Fig 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfgzG.jpg)

Just can't do this limit.. I faintly remember something similar to this appeared in first year math, but couldn't locate it.

In this question, f is continuous and bounded, so its integrals (i.e. $\int f$, 
 $\int \int f$ ,...) will be continuous, and can be eliminated by the exp. term. I first tried to integrate by part, integrating f. That would cancel the $n^n$ term and the $(n-1)!$ term, but ended up in an n times integral of f.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_inversion_formula

Comment: So Post's Inversion Formula. Thank you.